# Popularity formula (using votes and age)

Tags: math

I need to create a simple formula for determining the popularity of an item based on votes and age.

Here is my current formula, which needs some work:
30 / (days between post date and now) * (vote count) = weighted vote

Whenever a vost is cast for an item it checks if its weighted vote is > 300. If an item has a weighted vote more than 300 then it is promoted to the front page.

The problem is that this formula makes it very hard for older items to be promoted.
30 / 1 day * 10 votes = 300 (promoted)
30 / 5 days * 15 votes = 90 (not promoted)
30 / 30 days * 30 votes = 30 (not promoted)
30 / 80 days * 40 votes = 15 (not promoted)

How can I alter the formula to make it relatively easier for older items to be promoted (IE. make the above four weighted values fairly close together)?

Comment: Your question is better suited for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: It seems too low-level for Math Overflow and would likely be closed very quickly if posted there. But math.stackexchange.com might be an appropriate place.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3481214/223391 ?

Answer (score 0):

Just get a graph drawing program (maybe excel, maybe matlab, maybe GNUplot) and experiment with the formula until you feel it looks right.
There's no right or wrong with these things.

Answer (score 0):

Toss a logarithm on the amount of time it's been since the item was posted. Tweak the base and the constants involved. That'll take you most of the way there.